# Taking PDF Info and Exporting it to Specific Excel Cells

Tags: python

I've searched for an answer to this specific question and haven't found anything. The goal is taking data from invoices and pasting it into specific cells in excel. Anyone have a good resource for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf/1.13 to extract info from the PDF and https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt to write the info in Excel format? I'm assuming your input is in PDF format based on the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

For getting data out of PDF, use the pdf-miner https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/, for writing the data into excel files, use xlwt https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt and xlutils https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils